# How to find out when two picture boxes have collided in C# WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms

I am working on a game where if two objects( in the shape of two picture boxes) collide, the user loses a life. However, I am unsure on how I would use an if-else or switch case statement to determine when they have collided. I tried using this but it doesn't seem to much, so when one picture box's location is exact to the other one, it would do something. This served only as practice using a conditional statement for this part so it didn't do much :

```
if(pictureBox1.Location == pictureBox2.Location)
            {
                pictureBox1.Location = new Point(pictureBox1.Left - 10);
            }
```

Comment: Look into algorithms that detect 2d collision. Heres a good place to start https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Games/Techniques/2D_collision_detection

Comment: @SamMarion thanks for the link, I'll look into it.

Comment: The reason your code does not work is because Location is a specific point for the pictureBox (the very top left). The only way this if would ever be true is if the top left corners of each picture box were at the same point (and also only if they reference the same Point object I believe since you're using == instead of .Equals)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create `Rectangle`s and check for intersections:

```
var rect1 = new System.Drawing.Rectangle(pictureBox1.Location, pictureBox1.Size);
var rect2 = new System.Drawing.Rectangle(pictureBox2.Location, pictureBox2.Size);

if (rect1.IntersectsWith(rect2))
{
    // Here is your collision.
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this is really helpful! I am gonna play around with these comments and see hopefully a good outcome